# Nodejs - First argument must be a string or Buffer

Tags: node.js, http, httprequest

I keep getting this anoying error. Does someone know how to solve this? It does the http request but somewhere it seems I miss a JSON.stringify.

#### app.js

```
let server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
path = req.url;

if (path === undefined || path === '/') {
    res.end('Welcome... all-about-clash site.');
    } else {
        const options = {
            host: 'api.clashofclans.com',
            path: path,
            url: 'https://api.clashofclans.com' + path,
            method: 'GET',
            json: true,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer token'
            }
        };

        request(options, (error, response, body) => {
            if (!error) {
                res.write(JSON.stringify(body));
                res.end();
            } else {
                res.write(JSON.stringify(error));
                res.end();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Add console.log on your `JSON.stringify` results. I'm betting your JSON result is `undefined` or something like that.

Comment: @Chris you bet right ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a strange behaviour where the route of the `http.createServer` was `/favicon.ico`. I just needed to catch that route. What worked for me was:

```
    if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
    res.end();
    return;
}
```

In the first line inside the `http.createServer` method.